# Define TextBox Validation.Error Event at root (UserControl)

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I created a UserControl `MyTextBox : System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`. I added Custom validationRules to Databinding and also defined `Validation.Error` event in XAML.

I want to move the `Validation.Error` event to root (`MyTextBox`), so that I can handle it generically. I am unable to implement such method at Usercontrol.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I got my question answer. Here is implementation at load event

```
//Check whether Designer mode is open. If not then set Custom binding
if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue) == false)
        {
            SetBinding();
        }
```